# Angular2 updating JSON file

Tags: json, http, angular, post, server

I have hosted a JSON file on my server locally. I am working with angular2 right now and have a JSON object that is to be used to overwrite the original one in the JSON file hosted. How do I do that? I am really new to these concepts.

Comment: you wanna update `JSON` on server through angular 2 ?

Comment: not necessarily, what all methods can I use?

Comment: basically you need some resource on server such as REST api to tell server to do it. for this you can use expressjs

Answer (score 0):

cannot understand scenario clearly that what you want to achieve ?

cause if you want to change something on server meaning(JSON file) 
then you need server side scripting ie. NodeJS,PHP,Java  and angular 2 is only for client side so basically angular 2 has no access to change anything from server. Hope it helps or help me to clear scenario you are fighting.